# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.softserve.edu.test1.Chess

Tags: java, intellij-idea, исключения, компиляция

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить. проблему - уже третий день мучаюсь. Уже и Идею переустанавливала, и jdk перезагружала,  Path проверяла. Для пробы запускаю простейшую программку, но, все-равно. выдает одну и ту же ошибку.
[image: скрин программы и ошибки]

[![ProjectStructure[![][2]][2]][2]][3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300318/error-classnotfoundexception-in-intellij-idea.

Создайте класс Chess в папке src и попробуйте запустить.

Comment: Попробовала(((
Error:Internal error: (java.io.IOException) Cannot find IntelliJ IDEA project files at C:/Users/Àäìèíèñòðàòîð/IdeaProjects/MyProject
А ссылку я смотрела - вроде, у меня все так же

Comment: Возможно, проблема в русских буквах в путях к проекту. Переместить проект в папку без русских букв.

Comment: все написано английскими

Comment: Да, Morewind, вы правы - у меня в проекте в output path была  папка Администратор, а я думала, что это непринципиально, а важно, чтобы все папки в src были англ буквами. Вот я удалила тот проект. Создала новый и вместо адреса по умолчанию (с русскоязычной папкой) написала свой, где папки только на английском языке. и ЗАРАБОТАЛО!!!!СПАСИБО! Расцеловать готова - так благодарна. Я ведь чувствовала, что ошибка, скорее всего, глупая))))